# Pick an image in settings on Android

Tags: android, settings

I'm currently working on an Android application, and I want to let the user pick an image as background. Then I'm wondering if there is an easy way to launch the corresponding `Intent` using Preferences, or if I have to create my own custom class based on `Preference`?

Thanks.